# does this Javascript object store its state as the program goes on?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, state

I am playing [Untrusted](http://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/) to teach myself JS, and I am curious how a certain function is evaluated.

The 'level' robotMaze gives you the following code to work on:

```
/*
 * robotMaze.js
 *
 * The blue key is inside a labyrinth, and extracting
 * it will not be easy.
 *
 * It's a good thing that you're a AI expert, or
 * we would have to leave empty-handed.
 */

function startLevel(map) {
    map.getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    map.placePlayer(map.getWidth()-1, map.getHeight()-1);
    var player = map.getPlayer();

    map.defineObject('robot', {
        'type': 'dynamic',
        'symbol': 'R',
        'color': 'gray',
        'onCollision': function (player, me) {
            me.giveItemTo(player, 'blueKey');
        },
```

and right here is where the player is allowed to modify code, which controls a single moving object in a maze.

```
        'behavior': function (me) {
            // move randomly
            var moves = map.getAdjacentEmptyCells(me.getX(), me.getY());
            // getAdjacentEmptyCells gives array of ((x, y), direction) pairs
            me.move(moves[map.getRandomInt(0, moves.length - 1)][1]);



        }
    });
```

The rest of the code is only run once as far as I can tell to set up the board at the start.

```
    map.defineObject('barrier', {
        'symbol': '░',
        'color': 'purple',
        'impassable': true,
        'passableFor': ['robot']
    });

    map.placeObject(0, map.getHeight() - 1, 'exit');
    map.placeObject(1, 1, 'robot');
    map.placeObject(map.getWidth() - 2, 8, 'blueKey');
    map.placeObject(map.getWidth() - 2, 9, 'barrier');

    var autoGeneratedMaze = new ROT.Map.DividedMaze(map.getWidth(), 10);
    autoGeneratedMaze.create( function (x, y, mapValue) {
        // don't write maze over robot or barrier
        if ((x == 1 && y == 1) || (x == map.getWidth() - 2 && y >= 8)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (mapValue === 1) { //0 is empty space 1 is wall
            map.placeObject(x,y, 'block');
        } else {
            map.placeObject(x,y,'empty');
        }
    });
}
```

My question is, if I store or access values in variables or from inside the `map.defineObject`'s `'behavior'` property, in what scope are they evaluated, and how persistent are they? For example, I might want to make a dumb maze solver that always makes right turns; for that I need to define an orientation variable.

Testing shows that there is some kind of persistence, but I would like to know the formal answer just in case (rather than implicitly from a game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on how/where the variables are declared, which variables you are trying to access and how the scope is set for the `behavior` function. A more detailed discussion is in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope), but in your example:

1. The `moves` variable has local scope in the function, it will be destroyed when the function finishes executing;
2. If you modify the `me` parameter, it will survive the function exit, because it is passed as a reference;
3. Based on the snippets of code you posted, the `map` variable is global or is defined in an enclosing scope that contains the `behavior` function, so if you modify its data, those changes will also survive the function exit.

Comment: In other words, if 3. is true in the scope of `map`, 1. will not apply?

Comment: For example, if `map` is declared an a global scope (ie outside of all objects) then if you modify one of its existing members inside `behavior`, then that member will continue to hold that value after you leave the function.